# How to copy elements of a NSDictionary to a swift Dictionary?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, dictionary, nsdictionary

I need to mutate a `NSDictionary` in *swift*.

Hence I need to copy the elements of that `NSDictionary` to a *swift* `Dictionary`.

Something like the *Objective-C* equivalent of

```
[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:(nonnull NSDictionary *)];
```

Comment: You should simply stop using NSDictionary and NSMutableDictionary and just use a Swift dictionary with let (constant) or var (mutable).

Answer (score 2):

A Dictionary is a `struct` in swift, which is a value type.

```
let firstDictionary = ....
let copyOfirstDictionary = firstDictionary// This will copy the contents from first dictionary to another.
```